# Reading routines for constrained realization data

Tags: gcc, fortran

Can anyone describe shortly or give a command for the reading routines on [this](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/galform/cr/data.shtml#routine) MPA site?
I don´t now what to do with these Fortran files on my Fedora 17 32bit with gcc-Version 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2).
For example, the `ReadGalCat.F`:

```
program ReadGalCat



integer*4 ngals

integer*4, dimension(:), allocatable :: IdGal,InGroup,MassGroup,Code

real*4, dimension(:), allocatable :: PosX,PosY,PosZ,VelX,VelY,VelZ
real*4, dimension(:), allocatable :: LumTotB,LumTotV,LumTotI,LumTotK,&
     &LumBulB,LumBulV,LumBulI,LumBulK


real*4, dimension(:), allocatable :: CGas,Stellar,Bulge,SFR,ZLast,VirmLast,Vc


character*100 base
character*100 ext
character*100 fname

implicit none


!base='/mybase/'
!ext='myext.halos'

base='/gpfs/mpa/hmathis/WebSiteCR/LCDM/'
ext='cat_cutLum.gals'


fname=base(1:len_trim(base))//ext

print *,'Reading : ',fname



open(1,file=fname,form='unformatted',status='old')

read(1) ngals
print*,'ngals : ',ngals



allocate(IdGal(ngals),InGroup(ngals),MassGroup(ngals),Code(ngals))
allocate(PosX(ngals),PosY(ngals),PosZ(ngals),VelX(ngals),VelY(ngals),VelZ(ngals))
allocate(LumTotB(ngals),LumTotV(ngals),LumTotI(ngals),LumTotK(ngals),&
     &LumBulB(ngals),LumBulV(ngals),LumBulI(ngals),LumBulK(ngals))
allocate(CGas(ngals),Stellar(ngals),Bulge(ngals),SFR(ngals),ZLast(ngals),VirmLast(ngals),Vc(ngals))




read(1) IdGal ! the index of the particle the galaxy is associated with
read(1) InGroup ! the index (i.e. the rank in the halo cat file) of the halo hosting the galaxy          
read(1) MassGroup ! the number of particles of that halo (found by the groupfinder)
read(1) Code ! 0 for central galaxy, 1 for satellite galaxy



read(1) PosX ! comoving position of particle attached to the galaxy SGX in kpc/h (origin = Milky Way)
read(1) PosY ! --- SGY in kpc/h (origin = Milky Way)
read(1) PosZ ! --- SGZ in kpc/h (origin = Milky Way)
read(1) VelX ! peculiar velocity of the particle attached to the galaxy in km/s
read(1) VelY ! ---
read(1) VelZ ! ---


read(1) LumTotB ! total B band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumTotV ! total V band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumTotI ! total I band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumTotK ! total K band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumBulB ! bulge B band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumBulV ! bulge V band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumBulI ! bulge I band luminosity in Lsol
read(1) LumBulK ! bulge K band luminosity in Lsol

read(1) CGas ! mass of cold gas in Msol/h
read(1) Stellar ! total stellar mass in Msol/h
read(1) Bulge ! bulge stellar mass in Msol/h
read(1) SFR ! total (starburst+quiescent) SFR during last redshift interval in Msol/h/year

read(1) ZLast ! redshift when the galaxy was last a central galaxy
read(1) VirmLast ! virial mass of the halo when the galaxy was last a central galaxy
read(1) Vc ! disk circular velocity in km/s


close(1)


print*, 'Read ...'


print* ,'min,max PosX : ',minval(PosX),maxval(PosX)
print* ,'min,max PosY : ',minval(PosY),maxval(PosY)
print* ,'min,max PosZ : ',minval(PosZ),maxval(PosZ)


print* ,'min,max VelX : ',minval(VelX),maxval(VelX)
print* ,'min,max VelY : ',minval(VelY),maxval(VelY)
print* ,'min,max VelZ : ',minval(VelZ),maxval(VelZ)

print* ,'min,max IdGal : ',minval(IdGal),maxval(IdGal)
print* ,'min,max Code : ',minval(Code),maxval(Code)
print* ,'min,max InGroup : ',minval(InGroup),maxval(InGroup)
print* ,'min,max MassGroup : ',minval(MassGroup),maxval(MassGroup)


print* ,'min,max LumTotB : ',minval(LumTotB),maxval(LumTotB)
print* ,'min,max LumTotV : ',minval(LumTotV),maxval(LumTotV)
print* ,'min,max LumTotI : ',minval(LumTotI),maxval(LumTotI)
print* ,'min,max LumTotK : ',minval(LumTotK),maxval(LumTotK)

print* ,'min,max LumBulB : ',minval(LumBulB),maxval(LumBulB)
print* ,'min,max LumBulV : ',minval(LumBulV),maxval(LumBulV)
print* ,'min,max LumBulI : ',minval(LumBulI),maxval(LumBulI)
print* ,'min,max LumBulK : ',minval(LumBulK),maxval(LumBulK)

print* ,'min,max ColdG : ',minval(CGas),maxval(CGas)
print* ,'min,max Stellar : ',minval(Stellar),maxval(Stellar)
print* ,'min,max Bulge : ',minval(Bulge),maxval(Bulge)
print* ,'min,max SFR : ',minval(SFR),maxval(SFR)

print* ,'min,max ZLast : ',minval(ZLast),maxval(ZLast)
print* ,'min,max Virm : ',minval(VirmLast),maxval(VirmLast)
print* ,'min,max Vc : ',minval(Vc),maxval(Vc)


stop

end
```

Comment: As Fortran code, you compile it with a Fortran compiler, such as gfortran.   Then run the executable.  This example appears to summarize the data to the terminal.  So you probably use the reading portion as an example to include in your own code.  You will have to change the directory "base".

Comment: If you don't want to use Fortran, use the documentation and this example to guide you in writing a reader in another language.  For that approach, you might want to run this example to have comparison results to use to check your code.

Comment: Read any tutorial about using a compiler and what the system paths mean.

Comment: Thank´s, how to change the directory "base"? Does that mean the script points to a or the catalog?

Comment: I tried to compile, but get this: klauslang@Fedq7 ReadGalCat]$ gfortran ReadGalCat.f90
ReadGalCat.f90:23.13:

implicit none
             1
ReadGalCat.f90:21.19:

character*100 fname
                   2
Fehler: Anweisung IMPLICIT NONE bei (1) kann nicht auf Anweisung Daten-Deklaration bei (2) folgen
[klauslang@Fedq7 ReadGalCat]$ Any idea what this mean?